# Conditionally calling a specific column in R

Tags: python, r, parsing

I have a .gz file that contains a large text file. The structure looks something like this:

```
propVarQ,0.1
multiplier,2.0
p,1,chr1,3
p,1,locus1,80828536,35.735,0.43562663
p,1,snp,1,80828735,G/A,GGGGGGAG,G,0.9166667
p,1,p,7699,0.09534625
p,1,p,317,0.09534625
p,1,p,6181,0.09534625
p,1,p,6570,0.09534625
p,1,p,2370,0.09534625
```

this is repeated about 1000 times. I need to parse this in R (though python is an option too, but I'm more familiar with R) so that it returns the 2nd value in the line (in this case 1), and the 8th value in the line (in this case G) for ONLY the rows where the 3rd value in the line is "snp" (line 5 in this case). In this example my desired outcome is:

```
1 G
```

Here is what I have come to so far:

```
maf <- file("file.gz")
maflist <- strsplit(readLines(maf), ",")
close(maf)

maflist[maflist[,3]=="snp",]
```

However I get *incorrect number of dimensions*. I ran into trouble reading in the file since there aren't equal numbers of columns in each row, which is why I ended up using `strsplit`. If there is a better way, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strsplit returns a list where each list item contains a vector of the split values. So the length of the list is the same length as your input. You cannot index down into it like matrix as you've done. You could do something like this

```
maflist[sapply(maflist, '[', 3)=="snp",]
```

To subset the list to get only the rows where the third item in the vector is "snp".

You know, `awk` would make this super easy if you're on a unix machine. Something like

```
read.table(pipe("gunzip -c file.gz | awk -F',' '$3==\"snp\"{ print $2, $8}'"))
```

Comment: I ditched R completely and just used your awk command. It works perfectly. I recently learned about awk and am loving it more and more. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `data.table`'s `fread`:

```
fread("gunzip -c file.txt.gz | grep ',snp'", select=c(2,8))
```

We unzip the file and `grep` for those rows that contain `,snp` and then we just select the columns `2` and `8` using the `select` argument.

This gives:

```
#    V2 V8
# 1:  1  G
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps read the lines in and filter them to contain just those you're interested in

```
lines = readLines(maf)
lines = lines[grep(",snp,", lines), fixed=TRUE]
```

and then read the selected lines as a data.frame from a text connection

```
snps = read.delim(textConnection(lines), sep=",", header=FALSE)
```